# Plots in version 10.0 look washed out compared to previous versions

Tags: plotting, graphics

Recently installed the new version but I can't get the graphics to look the way I want them to.  If I run this code

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

in version 8.0 I get this:

[image]

But if I run the same code in version 10.0 I get this:

[image]

(I exported the images using the `Export` command to post them here, but the issue is present in the notebook as well - they look exactly like this when plotted)

The blue trace looks better, in my opinion, in the older version.  It's more vibrant, less faded or washed out.  This also applies to the numbers on the axes, which look gray in the version 10.0 plot but black in the version 8.0 plot.

How can I reproduce the old graphics?  Why did they make this change?  Maybe the newer version is better for the screen, but I am trying to make publication-quality plots and need the old style.

Comment: How exactly did you export? Interactively or programmatically? Please provide info or code.

Comment: Always with `Export`.  I've never once found that interactive prompt within the notebook to be useful. Do you know how to disable it?

Comment: `PlotTheme - > "Classic"`? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html

Comment: Based on the updated plot themes that came with MMA10: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/plot-themes/

Comment: Thanks @blochwave, that fixed it! (also, answered my own question about disabling the suggestion bar, in the preferences menu)

Comment: You can disable "Preferences->Show suggestion bar after last input"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the default setting for the option [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html) for graphics functions with [`$PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$PlotTheme.html).

```
$PlotTheme = "Classic"
```

or make that change only locally

```
Block[{$PlotTheme = "Classic"},Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

or more simply by specifying it as an option

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thick,PlotTheme - > "Classic"]
```

as explained by @blochwave in the comments.